# How to filter with non-ascii characers from column in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-like

I have values that contain non-ascii characters that I would like to filter and count how many times they occur in the column:

Ex

```
Human Soft Canada (HSC) inc. - VAR
```

I want to pull all values in col1 that contain '()' - essentially take anything that has '()' populated using (*).

This is my code right now with a like statement but it does not seem to be working

```
SELECT * FROM table where col1 like '%(*)%';
```

Comment: Please add how you'd like the output to look like

Comment: Can you please clarify the requirement? The ( and ) characters are in the ASCII set. Are you looking for non-ASCII characters or parenthesis? If you're looking for open and close parenthesis, your like filter should be '%(%)%' instrad of having an asterisk inside the parenthesis.

Comment: To count paren occurrences...  `regexp_count(col1, '[\\(\\)]')`

Comment: Actually, the backslashes are not necessary here, so... `regexp_count(col1, '[()]')`